# Find the output node in a AlexNet implementation in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am using [this](https://github.com/huanzhang12/tensorflow-alexnet-model) implementation of a Pre-Trained **Alexnet**.
I have re-trained it with my own trainings data and by doing that I received a checkpoint of the re-trained **AlexNet**.

I want to use it now to classify an image. 
As far as I understand, I need to provide two things for a classification:

1. Input node with the image that I want to classify
2. Output node for the result

I am receiving a list of all nodes using

```
for op in graph.get_operations():
    print(str(op.name), op.outputs)
```

However, I cannot figure out the output node this way. 
The list of all nodes can be seen [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/ZVqi7yDL).

Is my approach wrong? I am not very experienced with tensorflow, I appreciate any help. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: You can use [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron) to visualize the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Call `model.summary()` to print a useful summary of the model, which includes:

- Name and type of all layers in the model.
- Output shape for each layer.
- Number of weight parameters of each layer.
- The inputs each layer receives
- The total number of trainable and non-trainable parameters of the model.

Also, you can use `model.layers[]` to print the layer information.

**Example:** I have defined a simple model here and displayed its summary using `model.summary()` and also the layer information using `model.layers[]`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D, Conv2D, Dense, Dropout, Flatten, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model


# Add the layers 
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), input_shape=(424,424,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3)))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3)))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(.3))#test
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3)))
model.add(Dropout(.3))
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(424,424,3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

# Model summary 
model.summary()
```

Output -

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 422, 422, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 140, 140, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 140, 140, 32)      2080      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 138, 138, 64)      18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 46, 46, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 46, 46, 64)        4160      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 46, 46, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 44, 44, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 14, 14, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 14, 14, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 12544)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNo (None, 12544)             50176     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 25090     
=================================================================
Total params: 138,722
Trainable params: 113,634
Non-trainable params: 25,088
_________________________________________________________________
```

To print the layer information after building the model -

```
# To print all the layers of the Model
print("All the Layers of the Model:")
for layers in model.layers:
    print(layers)
print("\n")

# To print first layer OR Input layer of the Model
print("Input Layer of the Model:","\n",model.layers[0],"\n")

# To print last layer OR Output layer of the Model
print("Output Layer of the Model:","\n",model.layers[-1])
```

Output -

```
All the Layers of the Model:
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7faa09294550>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x7faa09294cf8>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7faa09294d30>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7faa0044e780>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x7faa0046fda0>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7faa09294f98>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dropout object at 0x7faa00477da0>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7faa0046ff60>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x7faa004412b0>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dropout object at 0x7faa00477f60>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Flatten object at 0x7faa004802b0>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization_v2.BatchNormalization object at 0x7faa003d0b00>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7faa00441588>


Input Layer of the Model: 
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7faa09294550> 

Output Layer of the Model: 
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7faa00441588>
```